# SSML in text response for API.AI

Tags: actions-on-google

I received the following in my acceptance letter for my bot:

> NOTE: In the future, Actions on Google will be available on more
>   Assistant surfaces. While we don’t have anything to announce at this
>   time, we do ask that you fine-tune your text-to-speech strings so that
>   they are optimized for visual display. Alternatively, you can contact
>   support to request to be temporarily opted-out of visual output.

I have:

```
<speak>To move, you can say "top left", <break time="0.5s"/><prosody rate="slow">"top"</prosody>, <break time="0.5s"/>"top right",  <break time="0.5s"/>"left",<break time="0.5s"/> <prosody pitch='x-low'> "middle"</prosody><break time="0.5s"/>and so on</speak>
```

in one of my API.AI responses. This causes the text output to be shown with the SSML when I go to https://bot.api.ai/9d6df2cb-6627-40b7-9c11-9e93fb1ee4c6 and type "how to move".
When Google Home Actions is integrated to the assistant on other devices, will the SSML be removed properly?

Answer (score 0):

While API.AI doesn't correctly support SSML (at least not yet), the point of using it is so other Assistants will handle it correctly. API.AI also doesn't support other integrations with Actions on Google correctly. Other Assistants aren't (yet) supported at all, but presumably when they are they will handle SSML correctly (the display version will show the text - anything spoken will use the SSML markup).

If you want to test it, using the Google Home Emulator or an actual Google Home is still your best bet.

Comment: From my experience, API.AI does support it. When API.AI speaks back to me, I hear the SSML correctly. The issue is not about testing, but how it will appear on other devices that are not Google home. E.g. Google watch and phone

https://bot.api.ai/9d6df2cb-6627-40b7-9c11-9e93fb1ee4c6

Comment: You indicated that accessing it through bot.api.ai didn't support SSML, and that had been my experience as well. I'm not sure where you're seeing where API.AI does handle SSML for any of its outputs (as opposed to going through Google Home.)

Comment: I've added clarifying text about other non-Home Assistants.